# Mapping issue between AWS SQS and its linked Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, message-queue

**Background**

I have a function with this signature:

```
public string Function(MyCommand cmd, ILambdaContext context)
```

Where `MyCommand` is:

```
public class MyCommand 
{
    public string Url { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Email { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

If I test my lambda on the AWS UI with this body:

```
{
    'Url': 'https://www.google.com/',
    'Email': 'myemail@gmail.com'
}
```

I get the result I want. I have logging in place, on the cloudwatch log, for my lambda I see the following as expected:

```
Received json: {'Url': 'https://www.google.com/', 'Email': 'myemail@gmail.com'}
```

**The issue**

I have also an SQS queue set up with a trigger on it for my Lambda. If I add the same JSON message to that queue I get the following log output:

```
Received json: {'Url': null, 'Email': null}
```

So it looks like my lambda *is* correctly triggered, because it hits my log code, but the values arrive empty.

***What could be the cause of this?***

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#example-standard-queue-message-event

Comment: That doesn't help at all, the documentation over complicates what should be really simple and doesn't provide any troubleshooting tips.

Comment: What part of the **"Example Amazon SQS message event (standard queue)"** is unclear? Also: please just add a basic log statement that logs the actual incoming message before any parsing happens. That way it would have been obvious what format the data is actually in vs. what you expect it to be?

Comment: @luk2302 Well, can the message be freeform or does it have to be that? And if so, how do find all that info.

Comment: The message is ALWAYS in that form and what you send into SQS is contained within the `body` section.

Comment: Aha, cool. Any way to generate that message for me so I can do that repeatedly from code? And how does the body content work if I use a complex type as parameter for the function (so that's MyCommand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Process SQS messages within a Lambda function, you need to accept the `SQSEvent` data type. Though you sent only the `MyCommand` payload from SQS, when it reaches the lambda function, the message is transformed into `SQSEvent`

```
public string Function(SQSEvent sqsEvent, ILambdaContext context)
{
    return sqsEvent.Records.First().Body;
}
```

p.s. To access `SQSEvent` in the lambda function, you need to install the following NuGet package: `Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents`

Comment: This little change and making sure I don't have any \t \n \r in the json string, from that body, before I deserialize did the trick! Nothing else needed to be changed.